# How can a directory/folder name affect page rendering?

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, dreamweaver

How can the name of a folder/file affect how a page renders client width in Firefox v16.0.2?

I locally developing a website using CSS, jQuery, HTML, & notepad++ as my editor.  I also have to use dreamweaver (DW) during site testing, CMS, & production deployment.  Using DW is a non-negotiable aspect of this project, but the site is moving from DW in a year or two so DW integration is supposed to be minimal.  I suspect the issue lies with DW, but I need help rooting it out.

The issue is that the homepage, and only the homepage, renders differently depending on the name of the folder.  When opening the homepage from the top level directory, named *siteBeta*, the page renders in a smaller width than it should.  If I copy the entire contents of *siteBeta* to a folder w/any other name, rename the *siteBeta* folder, or rename the homepage.html document the page renders properly.

I have a sneaking suspicion that there is a hidden file or file association somewhere, but I'm at a loss to find it.

Of course the easy solution would be to rename the file/folder, which is the course I am taking now, but it is driving me crazy as to why this is happening.

I've pored over the output of both a properly rendered page, and the improperly rendered page in firebug.  Scrolling through all aspects of layout, computed output, and DOM elements.  The only difference I can find is the width properties (clientWidth, offsetWidth, etc.) of the page.

This defect occurs with CSS references removed, jQuery references removed, and with all references removed.  The only constant is that *siteBeta*/homeTab/homePage.html renders the client width ~100px narrower than every other page.  This happens if opened in a browser through dw, or via directly opening the file in a browser.

The real kicker is that IE8 doesn't have this issue rendering clientWidth properly.

I will gladly provide any additional info needed, and I thank you in advance for your time & any hints or direction you may provide.

Comment: I would suggest looking into CSS references and see if there is an error with the path your are specifying.  You could possibly be referencing a file in /siteBeta/filename.css or something of the like.

Comment: Did you tested it in Chrome??? Are there any error's in the console log of chrome (press F12) or in Firefox ( press CTRL + SHIFT + K )

Comment: Could it be a perissions issue?>

Comment: Also check the apache error log for any errors. mayby that explains a lot...

Comment: Is it possible that you zoomed that page at some point and the zoom is persisting?

Comment: Need to see your code mate, link?

Comment: @Boris You got it man!  I knew in my heart it was something simple like this.  You rock, and thank you.  Sincerely, Me

Comment: Always hit Ctrl+0 if something is weird

Comment: @Rick Good to hear it's not something weird and complicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my issue is that I had used page zoom (Ctrl+/-) at some point, and it was persisting.  I feel silly missing something so simple.

@[Boris Zbarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720912/boris-zbarsky), Thank you for suggesting this fix.  I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have an issue with relative paths?

Perhaps try using Fiddler to see if some css references aren't being found.

Else it could be caching so double check..

- Relative Paths
- Fiddler
- Caching

Comment: Thank you Lee, @Boris got it. That is was something so simple is both frustrating, and a relief.